# import torch ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'

Tags: python, pytorch

Help me understand few things, im new with python and all these depended libraries.

I m trying to run a project which is written in python. Git repository can be found here: https://github.com/ifzhang/FairMOT

On anaconda prompt I have been running these commands:

```
conda create -n FairMOT
conda activate FairMOT
conda install pytorch==1.2.0 torchvision==0.4.0 cudatoolkit=10.0 -c pytorch
cd ${FAIRMOT_ROOT}
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

All being successfully installed

I have performed all the steps that were listed in the Readme file

Now there is training step which requires to run shell script.

Assuming the fact that shell script would not be called on anaconda prompt, I switched to git bash, and I run the script (keeping in mind of path)

```
 sh experiments/crowdhuman_dla34.sh
```

it throws error

```
Sanam@LAPTOP-NPVR76P7 MINGW64 /f/NTNU/Deep learning/Repositories/FairMOT (master)
$ sh experiments/crowdhuman_dla34.sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "train.py", line 10, in <module>
import torch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

Question is: is there any other console where I need to run this command other than git bash? it would definitely not work on anaconda prompt. what im doing wrong?

coming back to anaconda prompt, when I test import there, it worked

```
  (FairMOT) F:\NTNU\Deep learning\Repositories\FairMOT>python
  Python 3.7.9 (default, Aug 31 2020, 17:10:11) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on 
  win32
  Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
  >>> import torch
  >>>
```

where & how do I run this command? so that it would work?is running on git bash not good?

thanks in advance!!

PS:
I have already tried reinstalling, activation/ deactivation of environment but it does not work

Comment: git bash is different from anaconda's terminal or prompt. git bash uses the local environment of your PC and that's the reason it doesn't work. You are calling the torch module on a python interpreter which was installed on your PC, not in an anaconda environment. What I'll suggest you is open the bash or sh file and see what does it do. Then perform those commands in bash file manually on Anaconda prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Pls. create a virtual envrionment first, then install all the dependencies there. Use the same venv in anaconda and run the bash script in any terminal with the venv activated.

Also, you can run `which python` to ensure you are installing and then importing it from same python interpreter